# Accessing a array inside class constructor and function

Tags: php, oop

What's the best practice to access config from functions and classes?
The below code is working, but it seems the wrong way.

How I could improve this? I'm free to change every part.

**config.php**

```
return [
    'ENVIRONMENT'  => 'development',
    'DB_HOST'  => '127.0.0.1'
];
```

**index.php**

```
$config = require 'config.php';
$config = (object) $config;
...
$router->get('/test/user/create', function() {
    global $config;
    $login = new \Demo\Login($config);
    ...
    _view('main');
});
...
function _view($page){
    global $config;

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    require_once('../view/'.$page.'.php');
}
```

**Login.php**

```
public $config = '';

public function __construct($config) {
    $this->config = $config;
    echo $this->config->ENVIRONMENT;
}
```

Comment: First thing, don't inject whole config, but just options (part) which you need.

Comment: @Michał Sznurawa I need much of them, Means it will not make sense to inject let say 20 config variables.

Comment: So you can inject array/config containing all 20. You should group logically your config options. If you need so many options, then maybe you need as well to think about dividing some class into a few smaller, following single responsibility principle. If you have many options, that may indicate, that your class is responsible for too many things.

Comment: @Michał Sznurawa this is a point where I should think about. I'm looking for some ideas how I could eliminate the global variables as they seem somehow wrong to me.

Comment: Are you working on own framework?

Comment: @Michał Sznurawa I'm using this as starter for all projects, to avoid usage of any framework.